# i can not watch youtube full screen videos on the monitor

Tags: firefox, multiple-monitors, video, youtube

I have just got a new monitor to connect it to the laptop.
I have opened Firefox in both screens. When i make full screen mode on the monitor and want to surf the web on the laptop at the same time, the full screen mode just goes off to normal one. Is there a way to watch full screen mode videos on youtube and surf the web on my laptop as well?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use the HTML5 mode, which will fix the Problem for all videos that support HTML.
Go to www.youtube.com/html5 to enable it.
Or you can use one of these workarounds:
http://www.webupd8.org/2012/10/ubuntu-multi-monitor-tweaks-full-screen.html